# Method annotated with @KafkaListener is not propagating the exception encountered. Unable to invoke my retry Configuration due to this

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka, spring-retry

I have a Kafka Listener method annotated with @kafkaListener. It takes in an argument of type Message and also an Acknowledgement. I process the received message and do manual commits using acknowledgement.acknowledge(). I have set the retry template on the container. The retry policy is defined exception specific. For this purpose, I have created my own RetryPloicy class and extended with ExceptionClassifierRetryPolicy. In that class, depending upon the exception received, I return AlwaysRetryPolicy, NeverRetryPolicy and SimpleRetryPolicy. The problem that I am encountering is, when a DataAccessException occurs during the processing of the message in the listener method, I would like to retry forever and I have configured the retry policy accordingly, but the listener method always throws a ListenerExecutionFailedException instead of the encountered exception which was thrown below the stack up until the listener method from the message processing methods above. Since this exception is thrown by the listener, my retry config doesn't work as expected.

Sample code is below:

```
    @KafkaListener(topics = "topicName", containerFactory = "kafkaListenerContainerFactory")
    public void listenToKafkaTopic(@Payload Message<SomeAvroType> message, Acknowledgement ack){
      SomeAvroType type = message.getPayLoad();
      type.processIncomingMessage();
      ack.acknowledge();
   }
```

Retry Policy Configuration

```
    @component 
    public class MyRetryPolicy extends ExceptionClassifierRetryPolicy
     {
      @PostConstruct
      public void init(){
        final SimpleRetryPolicy simpleRetryPolicy = new SimpleRetryPolicy();
        simpleRetryPolicy.setMaxAttempts(3);

        this.setExceptionClassifier( new Classifier<Throwable, RetryPolicy>()
          {
            @Override
            public RetryPolicy classify( Throwable classifiable ){

            // Always Retry when instanceOf TransientDataAccessException
            if ( classifiable instanceof TransientDataAccessException)
            {
                return new AlwaysRetryPolicy;
            }
            else if(classifiable instanceOf SomeOtherException){

              return simpleRetryPolicy; 
           }

            // Do not retry for other exceptions
            return new NeverRetryPolicy();
          }
       } );
     }
   }
```

I use most of the auto configuration provided on the container and hence I auto wire the ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory in my Retry Config class.

```
    @configuration
    public class RetryConfig{


     @Bean
     public RetryTemplate retryTemplate(@Autowired @Qualifier("kafkaListenerContainerFactory")ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory factory;){

       RetryTemplate retryTemplate = new RetryTemplate();
       retryTemplate.setRetryPolicy(new MyRetryPolicy());
       FixedBackOffPolicy fixedBackOffPolicy = new FixedBackOffPolicy()
       fixedBackOffPolicy.setBackOffPeriod(1000l);
       retryTemplate.setBackOffPolicy(fixedBackOffPolicy);

       factory.setRetryTemplate(retryTemplate);
       factory.setAckOnError(false);
       factory.setRecoveryCallback(//configure recovery after retries are exhausted and commit offset)

      }
    }
```

When I run this in debug mode, and I throw a TransientDataAccessException in processIncomingMessage(), I expect to retry always but the listener method doesn't throws the propagated exception but it throws ListenerExecutionFailedException and the cause(e.getCause()) of it is the TransientDataAccessException. Therefore the retry policy always evaluates to NeverretryPloicy. Is there a way where in the listener would throw the propagated exception so that my retry config executes correctly?

Answer (score 0):

See the [BinaryExceptionClassifier](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-retry/blob/5a1a3bfbf3ebc2c336f2383cb75faf8bd660c708/src/main/java/org/springframework/retry/policy/SimpleRetryPolicy.java#L109-L126) and its `traverseCauses` property.

```
/**
 * Create a binary exception classifier.
 * @param defaultValue the default value to use
 * @param typeMap the map of types to classify
 * @param traverseCauses if true, throwable's causes will be inspected to find
 * non-default class
 */
public BinaryExceptionClassifier(Map<Class<? extends Throwable>, Boolean> typeMap, boolean defaultValue,
        boolean traverseCauses) {
    super(typeMap, defaultValue);
    this.traverseCauses = traverseCauses;
}
```

Comment: I have seen this. A simple retry policy has a constructor to pass in an instance of BinaryExceptionClassifier. But along with this I have to pass in the no of attempts too. Is there a way I can pass in the number of attempts depending on the exception. I know it's not straight forwarding. I am looking for an approach or a sample if you have.@Gary Russell

Comment: No, but you can use your current technique and subclass the `BinaryExceptionClassifier` and call `super.classify()` to determine which policy to return. Or, simply classify the `LEFE.cause()` instead. User exceptions are always wrapped in an LEFE.

Comment: I did not quite understand the subclassing BinaryExceptionClassifier technique. My understanding is I would write a class that extends BinaryExceptionClassifier. Not clear on the contents of the class. Like the constructor to be called and also how the appropriate policy will be returned by calling super.classify(). Any pseudocode would greatly help or detailed instructions. I searched for examples and could find none. @Gary Russell

Comment: Currently as a work around am calling the getCause() method on the classifiable of type Throwable in MyRetryPolicy class. This is giving me the exception that's thrown and which is wrapped inside ListenerExecutionFailedException. Using that and doing an instance of check and returning the appropriate retry policy. Please Let me know if this is a good practice

Comment: Yes; this is the best solution - I didn't notice that you wanted 3 different policies; subclassing would only support 2 policies. The user exception will always be the `LEFE.cause`.

Comment: Thanks for your quick responses. One last confirmation I would like to make here. LEFE.cause = listenerExecutionFailedExceptionObject.getCause()?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean. Simply `Throwable cause = classifiable.getCause()`. Then `if (cause instanceof ...`.

Comment: Thank you. That's the confirmation I needed. Probably my comment was confusing. @Gary Russell